# Find the index of the next greatest element in the array

Tags: algorithms, arrays

[image]

I know there is a stack based approach with O(N) complexity and O(N) space. Can B be created using O(1) space? Such as in place using a single loop or even some sorting algorithm ? If so, can you please provide a high level description of the algorithm ? I've been working on a solution for some time now and am unable to come up with anything.

Comment: Please type in the image. This will make it possible to find your question by text searching.

Comment: 1. Do you allow over-writing the elements of A, or do you require A to be preserved unchanged throughout the algorithm?  2. What is the stack-based approach you mention in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not hard to work from right to left:

```
B[n] = n+1
for i = n-1 to 1
  j = i+1
  while A[i] >= A[j] and j < n+1
    j=B[j]
  end
  B[i]=j
end
```

I think that's similar to the stack-based algorithm.

Edit:  This is listed in Wikipedia as also found by Barbay, Fischer and Navarro
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_nearest_smaller_values):

Barbay, Jeremy; Fischer, Johannes; Navarro, Gonzalo (2012), "LRM-Trees: Compressed indices, adaptive sorting, and compressed permutations", Theoretical Computer Science 459: 26–41,

Answer (score 1):

The output has size $n$. That gives you immediate $\Omega(n)$ lower bounds on space and time.

Comment: I think he asks whether it's possible to  compute the right answer whist allocaing space only for the B array.

Comment: @jjohn Then the question needs to be made more precise and rid of $O$-notation (at least regarding space).

Comment: Or you can talk about whether it's possible to do with linear time and constant additional space.